# How the inequality axiom ensures ordering?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let's consider a non-empty subset $\mathbb{P}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ called as the set of positive real numbers, that satisfies the following properties:

(i) if $a,b\in \mathbb{P} \Rightarrow a+b\in \mathbb{P}$

(ii) if $a,b \in \mathbb{P} \Rightarrow ab\in \mathbb{P}$

(iii) if $a\in \mathbb{R}$, exactly one of the following holds.
$$a\in \mathbb{P} $$$$a=0  $$$$-a\in \mathbb{P}$$

It's told that **The first two conditions ensure the compatibility of order with the operations of addition and multiplication, respectively**.

How ?

Also how the ordering of real numbers follows from the above axiom?

Comment: I don't even understand that statement. Isn't "$+$" the standard addition and "$\cdot$" the standard multiplication? What exactly does the author mean by "compatibility"? Isn't addition and multiplication compatible with ordering, and thus it is compatible on every subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I can't relate also, how the above axioms ensure that addition and multiplication can fit in with ordering ? I mean, how "sum of positive is positive" and "product of positive is positive" ensures ordering ?

Comment: @freakish: I think that the context here is an axiomatic development of the real numbers (e.g. Fitzpatrick's book "Advanced Calculus" and numerous others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering follows from the definition

$$a < b \iff b-a \in \Bbb P\tag{1}$$

Why is this a linear order? The third condition ensures that when $a,b \in \Bbb R$ we have $b-a \in \Bbb P$ so $a <b$, or $b-a=0$ so $a=b$ or finally $a-b=-(b-a) \in \Bbb P$, so $b < a$ then holds. So we get trichotomy.

If $a < b$ and $c$ is any real then we expect $a + c < b+c$ to hold as well, and this is also automatic as $(b+c) - (a+c) = (b-a)$ by standard group facts and so is in $\Bbb P$ and the order is preserved. And if $c >0$ we expect $ac < bc$ as well (compatibility with multiplication) and so $c \in \Bbb P$ (from $0 < c$ and the definition) and $b-a \in \Bbb P$ then gives $(b-a)c = bc - ac \in \Bbb P$ as $\Bbb P$ is closed under multiplication (condition 2). Condition 1 gives us that from $a < b$ and $c < d$ we can indeed conclude $a + c < b+d$ e.g. (check this).

Hope this helps understanding the rationale a bit.